# Are there standard questions for testing how an instructor grades calculus?

Tags: calculus, assessment, testing

My institution is now in the process of "standardizing" our calculus classes. One issue we have is the variation among instructors in grading problems. I am interested if there are ways to objectively study such variation and so my question is whether anyone knows of a standard set of questions where there is an agreed upon rubric as to how to grade the problem and also how to deduct points for cases that don't fall nicely into the rubric. I know these types of rubrics do exist for AP Calculus tests for example, so I was wondering if anyone in math ed has ever constructed a bank of such questions.

So as a brief example: consider the problem of finding the derivative of ln(sin(x) + tan(x)) that is worth, say 10 points. The rubric would have a breakdown of what points are awarded to each part (maybe +4 points for knowing to use chain rule, +2 for the derivative of each trig function, etc) but would also consider all the possible common student errors (such as ln(x+y) = ln(x) + ln(y)) and how to deduct points for them.

I'm not sure that such a set of problems whose grading had been standardized would actually answer my question, but I am thinking it might be a first step in understanding how much variation we have among the instructors and how to interpret it.

Comment: At my institution, we just do "cafeteria" grading for exams, write the rubrics together, and generally have one individual grading all one problem for uniformity across sections.  Homework is automated, and only a small quiz percentage would introduce instructor grading bias into final grades.

Comment: @StevenGubkin  We are trying to do the same but the problem I am being to see emerge is that we aren't producing uniformity: we are just redistributing the variance. Rubrics (instructors draw up) are great but the time when the wheels fall off is when a student answers in a way that the rubric doesn't cover (hence my example). I am seeing that some teachers grade a mistake based on when it occurs in the problem, others grade based on how significantly it affects the answer, etc. This is the main problem I am trying to gte a handle on

Comment: You answer it yourself when referring to the AP tests.  As far as other areas, I know many schools with multisection classes have common tests.  A key is written for the tests that gives a specific breakdown of the points for different parts of the question.

Comment: (cont.)  Yes, there is a possibility of different instructors not exactly following the key but so what (the tests are randomized in grading...sections mixed amongst graders).  Nothing is exact and slight differences average out over time and are "good enough".  Similarly if there are genuine alternate methods raised, this can be elevated to course leader during grading.

Comment: Now I know why some people hate Common Core: because it attempted introducing the same over-formalized concepts to elem/middle/high school. Breaking down and deducting points for this and that is one the most mind-numbing ideas one can come up with. Not only there is no joy of learning anymore, there is no joy of teaching (unless grading is offloaded to clueless TAs or Mechanical Turk drones, but I would not want to study in a uni where stuff like that is common).

Comment: @RustyCore  How is this related in any way to Common Core?

Comment: @StevenGubkin "because it attempted introducing the same over-formalized concepts to elem/middle/high school."

Comment: @RustyCore  Some truth to what you say but in my case, I just want to have an instrument that assesses how my instructors are grading and how consistently. I'm not really assessing the students so much as seeing how reliable the measures teachers give to them are

Comment: @MattBrenneman So you are norming your measurement tools, bringing the instructors to the level of merely lexical analyzers. Are they so bad that you cannot trust their judgment? Again, the same concept as in Common Core for grade school: no trust to individual teacher, instead over-formalization of curricula and testing. The computers are not smart enough yet to teach kids on their own, no problem, we'll pretend that humans are as two-bit as computers. Excuse my rant, could not help.

Comment: @RustyCore While discussion of the common core is almost certainly off-topic here, the fact is that it is merely a set of standards and guidelines for what students should know at a particular point in their educational careers.  You seem to be ranting against the assessments which are ostensibly written to be aligned with the common core, which is an entirely different issue.  Perhaps you should actually download the standards themselves, and have a look at how little they constrain teachers...

Comment: The thoughtfulness for the teach is when he writes the key.  This is an act that requires thinking.  The actual grading is mechanical (and becomes more so after doing a couple tests).  But so what.  That is an efficient way to grade, especially for large classes.  Time is limited.  Life is an optimization function within constraints.

Comment: Using a rigid grading scheme does not eliminate variation in how different instructors grade as different instructors apply the rigid scheme differently. If one cannot count on having qualified instructors exercising good judgment, then all is lost anyway.

Comment: @DanFox  I am not trying to eliminate the variation in the student scores due to the instructors. I am merely trying to quantify the variation from this source. Granted it would still be an apples-to-oranges comparison because I'm not actually observing the variation in the student scores due to the teachers on the actual exam the students took. But in any statistical study you always start with a test pilot study. It's imperfect with many weaknesses but you learn and you refine it. This is how statistics works. And our best hope to address this question is with data.

Comment: @RustyCore  I think you're misunderstanding my motivation. I suspect in a decent percentage of mathematics departments there is significant variation among how calc 1 instructors grade. In departments you'll see that there's a broad range of attitudes and behaviors regarding calculus. Some teachers are old school while others are much more liberal. And this doesn't reflect incompetence in any sense: it simply reflects different attitudes as to what calculus students should take away from the course. And it's a legitimate concern because what students today need from the course has changed.

Comment: @MattBrenneman "this doesn't reflect incompetence in any sense: it simply reflects different attitudes" -- This is what good educators do: they use their own techniques that work for them and for their class, they follow a relatively flexible syllabus by building their own coursework and tests. Quantifying the variation is the first step in producing a set of rigid guidelines, which will invariably stifle variability. This kills the human aspect of education. What is the point to attend a uni IRL if one can watch a video and then be graded by a computer? You are shooting your own foot.

Comment: @Rusty Core. You're absolutely right and the points you raise are spot on. Unfortunately things don't always work out the way you outlined. When you're teaching a course run by a course monitor, you often don't have any control over how the test questions are written. The reality is you have to play the hand you're dealt with. I have to deal with the situation at my University, which may not be ideal, but it's the one I have to work with.

Comment: @MattBrenneman You have a tough problem to solve and I feel for you. I have never seen anything like what you speak of (granted I've not taught too long), but I've found the rubriks are easier part (though they do get applied differently). The issue I've always seen with tests were the (very huge) differences in complexity of the tests themselves. I'm talking - same course -  one year would have problems that took the TA's 15 minutes for the hardest problem (whole test 50 minutes) the next year the whole test took 10 minutes for the slowest TA.